# The right MongoDB architecture for a font library?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, architecture, database, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB and NoSQL databases, and I'm trying to design a database architecture for a font library web-app.

**Font.js**

```
var FontSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    families: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Family' }], // Font families (ex: Sans-serif)
    name: String,           // Font name (ex: Helvetica)
    style: String,          // Font style (ex: Bold Italic)
    tags: [String],         // Array of tags
    file: {
        name: String,       // File name
        location: String,   // File location
    }
});
```

**Family.js**

```
var FamilySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MainFamily' },
    name: String
});
```

**MainFamily.js**

```
var MainFamilySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
```

I guess I'm thinking SQL here, and maybe the *Family* and *MainFamily* models are too much. I could embed these in a *Font* document but I have some questions :

- Is the architecture I posted right for the job?
- What happens if I want to **rename** a *Family* or *MainFamily* if     the names exist as strings in each *Font* document?
- How to **retrieve all the families or main families names** without retrieving all the fonts and then filter them out?

Comment: MongoDB is a way beyond nosql which includes functionalities of relational databases as well as NoSQL technologies. If you want to understand the architecture, please look at the [link](http://www.spokenbyyou.com/mongodb-way-beyond-nosql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This seems to be a RDBMS case -- as it stands. But you can simplify it into one collection (the equal of a table)
2. Yes, thats the way to 'de-normalize' it for NoSQL by including family names in each font document. You can rename all 'related' documents using update, $set and multi such as

   ```
   db.font.update({family: "Sans-Serif"}, {$set: {family: "Sans-serif"}}, {multi: true})
   ```
3. This is less friendly (and costly once your font table gets large) than RDBMS but one can achieve it using an aggregation. and you can also add some useful data such as the number of fonts under each family.

   ```
   db.font.aggregate({$match: {_id: "$familyName", total: {$sum: "$fontId" } )
   ```

Your goal is getting along the lines of

```
    {"_id": "Sans-serif", "total": 120},
    {"_id": "Serif": "total": 130},,,
```

the above is almost certainly incorrect since its off the cuff but check [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) for examples. Its easy and worth checking out.

As a second choice for 3. there is nothing wrong (in the NoSQL world) with using a table only for this use case, recognizing that this second convenience table might be inconsistent with the current font table even for a moment. aka if you just added a new font with a new family...so you must rebuild it on a regular basis, depending on the usage patterns. then use a mongo shell script spawned by crontab.

Comment: Sorry to not have answered before. The MongoDB aggregation is very efficient indeed! I use embedded documents and it works like a charm.

Comment: mongo's aggregation (pipeline) is awesome. howecver, some of my ones that dont have a $match operator (and thus select all) time out at 5 secs. if you reach that stage, then consider the olap (generated) table.